# Java equals causes ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, equals, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to compare two `String`s in two different arrays. `String`s are stored in `s1` and `s2` variables. This part works great, but if I add if condition, `if(s1.equals(s2)){/*...*/}`, I get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Look at these two screen shots:

In both cases arrays have same values. The only thing that was changed is the if condition.

**Image#1**
[image]

**Image#2**
[image]

**Code:**

```
        Vagon tmp = first;
        int stevec = 1;
        while(tmp != null){
            double trenutenVolumen = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < tmp.opisTovora.length; j++){
                trenutenVolumen += tmp.volumenTovora[j];
            }
            double lahkoDodamVolumna = tmp.volumen-trenutenVolumen;
            double lahkoDodamTeze = lokomotiva.najvecjaMasa-trenutnaTeza;

            System.out.println("len: "+tmp.opisTovora.length);
            if(tmp.tipTovora == tipTovora[0] && lahkoDodamVolumna >= volumenTovora[0] && trenutnaTeza+tezaTovora <= lokomotiva.najvecjaMasa){
                if(!tmp.tipTovora){
                    String s1 = tmp.opisTovora[0];
                    String s2 = opisTovora[0];
                    //if(s1.equals(s2)){
                        System.out.println(s1 + " == " + s2);
                        System.out.println("LAHKO DODAM TOVOR #" + (i+1) + " => V VAGON #" + stevec);
                        break;
                    //}
                }
                if(tmp.tipTovora){
                    System.out.println("LAHKO DODAM TOVOR #" + (i+1) + " => V VAGON #" + stevec);
                    break;
                }
            }

            stevec++;
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }
```

Comment: Exception shows 498 line number. Have look at it.

Comment: Is this code called multiple times. Because your 1st snapshot shows it multiple times printed values.

Comment: @Naman Gala Well, why is line 498 good in first case then?

Comment: Do you maybe have something in the else statement?

Comment: Yes, but always compare `"tekocina1"` with some other string

Comment: @Jure Don't have any else statement.

Comment: your `tmp.opisTovora[0]` getting reset somewhere. Because in your second snapshot, output shows execution for 1st time and then exception has occured. Please post the code which is calling this multiple times.

Comment: When you get "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0" is means you have an empty string.

Comment: Almost certainly you're getting the exception after the first iteration of your loop, and you don't iterate if the `if` statement is commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception is on this line - `String s1 = tmp.opisTovora[0]`. It means that `tmp.opisTovora` is an empty array, so `tmp.opisTovora[0]` is out of the bounds of that array.

It has nothing to do with `equals`.

Comment: But it cant be, it is the same array in both cases

Comment: @TheDubleM You haven't shown where you initialize `tmp.opisTovora`. You should try to print `tmp.opisTovora.length` before the line where the exception occurs.

Comment: Without the if -statement one breaks out of the loop after the first time. The first time seems to have a filled `tmp.opisTovora`. With the if-statement, being skipped, it seems `tmp.opisTovora` is emptied, and in a next step the error happens.

Comment: You should show whole code if it's not to big. Or at least the part where you set values of those arrays.

Comment: @Jure `Vagon tmp` is one of many elements in doubly linked list.

Comment: @TheDubleM - Right, it's a linked list.  And with the `if` commented out you only examine the first element.